# Lighting Dual depth peeling

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm doing Dual depth peeling. I want to ask you, how to properly. I have algorithm like this.

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, dualDepthFBOID);

    // Render targets 1 and 2 store the front and back colors
    // Clear to 0.0 and use MAX blending to filter written color
    // At most one front color and one back color can be written every pass
    glDrawBuffers(2, &drawBuffers[1]);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL_CHECK_ERRORS

    // Render target 0 stores (-minDepth, maxDepth, alphaMultiplier)
    glDrawBuffer(drawBuffers[0]);   
    glClearColor(-MAX_DEPTH, -MAX_DEPTH, 0, 0); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBlendEquation(GL_MAX);
    DrawScene(MVP, initShader);  

    // 2. Depth peeling + blending pass
    glDrawBuffer(drawBuffers[6]);
    glClearColor(bg.x, bg.y, bg.z, bg.w);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int numLayers = (NUM_PASSES - 1) * 2;
    int currId = 0;
    for (int layer = 1; bUseOQ || layer < numLayers; layer++) {
        currId = layer % 2;
        int prevId = 1 - currId;
        int bufId = currId * 3;

        glDrawBuffers(2, &drawBuffers[bufId+1]);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawBuffer(drawBuffers[bufId+0]);
        glClearColor(-MAX_DEPTH, -MAX_DEPTH, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Render target 0: RG32F MAX blending
        // Render target 1: RGBA MAX blending
        // Render target 2: RGBA MAX blending
        glDrawBuffers(3, &drawBuffers[bufId+0]);
        glBlendEquation(GL_MAX);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, depthTexID[prevId]);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, texID[prevId]);
        DrawScene(MVP, dualPeelShader, true,true);

        // Full screen pass to alpha-blend the back color
        glDrawBuffer(drawBuffers[6]);

        glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        if (bUseOQ) {
            glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED_ARB, queryId);
        }

        GL_CHECK_ERRORS

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, backTexID[currId]);
        blendShader.Use();       
             DrawFullScreenQuad();
        blendShader.UnUse();

        if (bUseOQ) {
            glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);
            GLuint sample_count;
            glGetQueryObjectuiv(queryId, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &sample_count);
            if (sample_count == 0) {
                break;
            }
        } 
        GL_CHECK_ERRORS 
    } 

    GL_CHECK_ERRORS

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    // 3. Final render pass
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, colorBlenderTexID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, depthTexID[currId]);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, texID[currId]);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, colorBlenderTexID);
    finalShader.Use(); 
        DrawFullScreenQuad();
    finalShader.UnUse();
```

I'm doing lighting in dualPeelShader, where are lighting each pass. This is resulting to extremly bright object. Should I do lighting in finalShader?

---EDIT----

Peel Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 vFragColor0;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 vFragColor1;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 vFragColor2;  


uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform float isObject;
uniform vec3 LightPosition;

uniform sampler2DRect  depthBlenderTex;
uniform sampler2DRect  frontBlenderTex;

in vec4 vOutColor;
in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in  vec3 eyeDirection;
in  vec3 lightDirection;

#define MAX_DEPTH 1.0

vec4 Lighted()
{
vec3 LightColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
float LightPower = 50;

// Material properties

vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = vOutColor.rgb;
vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3,0.3,0.3);

// Distance to the light
float distance = length( LightPosition - position );

// Normal of the computed fragment, in camera space
vec3 n = normalize( normal );
// Direction of the light (from the fragment to the light)
vec3 l = normalize( lightDirection);
// Cosvaryinge of the angle between the normal and the light direction,
// clamped above 0
//  - light is at the vertical of the triangle -> 1
//  - light is perpendicular to the triangle -> 0
//  - light is behvaryingd the triangle -> 0
float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n,l ), 0,1 );

// Eye vector (towards the camera)
vec3 E = normalize(eyeDirection);
// Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
vec3 R = reflect(-l,n);
// Cosvaryinge of the angle between the Eye vector and the Reflect vector,
// clamped to 0
//  - Lookvaryingg varyingto the reflection -> 1
//  - Lookvaryingg elsewhere -> < 1
float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0,1 );

return vec4(MaterialAmbientColor + MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance) +
MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,5) / (distance*distance),vOutColor.a);

}


void main(void)
{
float fragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
vec2 depthBlender = texture(depthBlenderTex, gl_FragCoord.xy).xy;
vec4 forwardTemp = texture(frontBlenderTex, gl_FragCoord.xy);

// Depths and 1.0-alphaMult always increase
// so we can use pass-through by default with MAX blending
vFragColor0.xy = depthBlender;

// Front colors always increase (DST += SRC*ALPHA_MULT)
// so we can use pass-through by default with MAX blending
vFragColor1 = forwardTemp;

// Because over blending makes color increase or decrease,
// we cannot pass-through by default.
// Each pass, only one fragment writes a color greater than 0
vFragColor2 = vec4(0.0);

float nearestDepth = -depthBlender.x;
float farthestDepth = depthBlender.y;
float alphaMultiplier = 1.0 - forwardTemp.w;

if (fragDepth < nearestDepth || fragDepth > farthestDepth) {
    // Skip this depth in the peeling algorithm
    vFragColor0.xy = vec2(-MAX_DEPTH);
    return;
}

if (fragDepth > nearestDepth && fragDepth < farthestDepth) {
    // This fragment needs to be peeled again
    vFragColor0.xy = vec2(-fragDepth, fragDepth);
    return;
}    

// If we made it here, this fragment is on the peeled layer from last pass
// therefore, we need to shade it, and make sure it is not peeled any farther
vFragColor0.xy = vec2(-MAX_DEPTH);

vec4 Color;
if(isObject == 0.0)
 Color = vColor;
else
 Color = Lighted();

if (fragDepth == nearestDepth) {
  vFragColor1.xyz += Color.rgb * Color.a * alphaMultiplier;
      vFragColor1.w = 1.0 - alphaMultiplier * (1.0 - Color.a);
} else {
    vFragColor2 += Color;
}
}
```

Blend Fragment Shader

```
 #version 330 core

 uniform sampler2DRect tempTexture; 

 layout(location = 0) out vec4 vFragColor;

 void main(void)
 {
vFragColor = texture(tempTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy); 
if(vFragColor.a == 0) 
    discard;
 }
```

Comment: No, you can (and probably should) do lighting in each pass. You should post the shader though. The problem lies in how you do the blending. If the object is too bright, you're probably adding colors without first multiplying them with the alpha value.

Comment: I add shaders. This is using phong shading model

Comment: Just want to throw out there that linked lists may be a more modern solution for whichever problem you're trying to solve (like order-independent transparency) with depth peeling. http://blog.icare3d.org/2010/06/fast-and-accurate-single-pass-buffer.html

Comment: Hi, I am also interested, have you solved, cimo?